# C# How to get the Circular Methods in a Project/Solution using ndepend in the latest version 2018.1.1

Tags: c#, .net, ndepend

I tried this code in NDepend version 2018.1.1 with some changes made to the original code which was posted on stackoverflow. It is to get the Methods which have a circular dependencies (i.e. calling each other and forming a cyclic/circular code)

But this Code does not seem to work in the latest nDepend.

Note: the only difference from the other code on StackOverflow is that this one has this according to version 2018.1.1 requirement;

```
let cycle = ExtensionMethodsEnumerable.Append(usersAndUsed,suspect)
```

The Code.....

```
    // <Name>Avoid methods of a type to be in cycles</Name>
warnif count > 0


from t in Application.Types
                 .Where(t => t.ContainsMethodDependencyCycle != null && 
                             t.ContainsMethodDependencyCycle.Value)

// Optimization: restreint methods set
// A method involved in a cycle necessarily have a null Level.
let methodsSuspect = t.Methods.Where(m => m.Level == null)

// hashset is used to avoid iterating again on methods already caught in a cycle.
let hashset = new HashSet<IMethod>()


from suspect in methodsSuspect
   // By commenting this line, the query matches all methods involved in a cycle.
   where !hashset.Contains(suspect)

   // Define 2 code metrics
   // - Methods depth of is using indirectly the suspect method.
   // - Methods depth of is used by the suspect method indirectly.
   // Note: for direct usage the depth is equal to 1.
   let methodsUserDepth = methodsSuspect.DepthOfIsUsing(suspect)
   let methodsUsedDepth = methodsSuspect.DepthOfIsUsedBy(suspect)

   // Select methods that are both using and used by methodSuspect
   let usersAndUsed = from n in methodsSuspect where
                         methodsUserDepth[n] > 0 && 
                         methodsUsedDepth[n] > 0 
                      select n

   where usersAndUsed.Count() > 0

   // Here we've found method(s) both using and used by the suspect method.
   // A cycle involving the suspect method is found!
   let cycle = ExtensionMethodsEnumerable.Append(usersAndUsed,suspect)

   // Fill hashset with methods in the cycle.
   // .ToArray() is needed to force the iterating process.
   let unused1 = (from n in cycle let unused2 = hashset.Add(n) select n).ToArray()

select new { suspect, cycle }
```

Comment: do you want all cycles of methods, or only cycles of methods defined in the same type?

Comment: Thanx for the reply Patrick. All the cyclic methods in the entire solution. It would also be better if they are grouped together based on which all methods forms that particular Cyclic/Circular call, so that it is easier to remove the cyclic dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query provided works fine on my end to find cycles of methods inside a type.

For general cycle of methods (no matter their parent type) just modify the beginning of the query this way.

```
//from t in Application.Types
//                 .Where(t => t.ContainsMethodDependencyCycle != null && 
//                             t.ContainsMethodDependencyCycle.Value)

// Optimization: restreint methods set
// A method involved in a cycle necessarily have a null Level.
let methodsSuspect = Application.Methods.Where(m => m.Level == null)
```

Also increase in the NDepend > Options > CQLinq query execution time-out to 60 seconds because the query can be slow on a large code base with all graph traversal.

Keep in mind that a cycle is not necessarily as simple as A calls B calls C calls A. A cycle is a set of methods where from any method, there is a path to any other method in the cycle. It can be quite complex like:
[image: Method cycle]

To visualize a method cycle just export it to the code graph:

[image: Export cycle methods to the graph]

Typically to break cycles, start by breaking mutual dependencies, like A calls B and B calls A.

A method cycle is not necessarily a code smell, many GoF design patterns for example rely on a method cycle.

Comment: thanx. Today its working fine on my end too. maybe there were some other issues the other day.